# Attach Java Agent to VM that doesn't support the attach mechanism

Tags: java, jvm, code-injection, agent

I'm trying to load an agent to a VM of another program, but unfortunately, the VM of this process doesn't support the attach mechanism, so when I try to attach my agent an `AttachNotSupportedException` is thrown:

```
System.out.println("Attaching to VM...");
VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid); //Exception
System.out.println("Attached to VM.");
System.out.println("Loading agent...");
vm.loadAgent(agentJar.getAbsolutePath(), "");
System.out.println("Detaching from VM...");
vm.detach();
System.out.println("Detached from VM.");
```

[image: image of stack trace]

Comment: If your application is running by 32 bit jvm & your attach program is 64 bit jvm you hit the AttachNotSupportedException. Can you check the version & bit of java used?

Comment: Besides the possibility of incompatibilities between the processes (which could get fixed), like a mismatching architecture, if a process does not support attaching, then it doesn’t support attaching.